# Multiple Web-API requests at the same time with different parameters in unittests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a Web-API which provides me with functions like `GetStuffFromDatabase(string user, string password)`.

I already have unit tests based on the NUnit framework to test the functions provided by the Web-API. But now I want to start testing the performance of the API when in use by several different users at the same time and I don't know how to do that.

How can I run NUnit tests with many different users at the same time?

I have already searched for a solution and often got a suggested answer corresponding to the `Parallelizable` attribute which I don't think helps me in this case as it "just" makes the functions within a testclass or the given scope run in parallel (as far as I understood).

What I need:

1. I need 1 function to run multiple times at the same time (to simulate multiple users using this one function at the same time).
2. If 1 is possible somehow I would like to give every call to the function a different user and password.

With the `TestCase` attribute I already have a working solution for the second point, but with the functions not running in parallel as I can just put this attribute above any function multiple times with different parameters on each.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There should be no reason you can't run multiple requests provided the server allow for it to be done.  The issue is when the client are from the same IP address.  When you make multiple request from same IP it looks like a service attack on server.  Most server will not allow multiple connections from same IP address.  If you PC is configured with an Ethernet card that has multiple IP addresses yo may be able to send requests so each parallel request comes from a different subnet.

Comment: just pointing out that you don't have unit tests, you have integration tests. what you are looking for is called "load testing"

Comment: Ok thank you for both comments. With a bit more research and in cooperation with some colleagues we found a solution with the NUnit framework. "load testing" was a good keyword to search for btw.